# Overriding C# subclass without having to create another class?

Tags: c#, subclass, overriding

I've subclassed Button from forms, because that's the only way I could override OnClick.

But now I have several buttons using my SubButton class and I want them to do different thing (in other words, I want their Action() method to do different stuff).

Sadly I'm clueless on how to override it's Action method afterwards, here's class declaration:

```
    class SubButton : Button
    {
        public void Action() { }

        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Action();
            base.OnClick(e);
        }
    }
```

And here's what I tried:

```
apply.Action = { };
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The OnClick() method raises the Click event.  Whose one and only purpose in life is to allow each button to have its own dedicated action when the button is clicked.  Why you are not using Click is hard to fathom, must be a case of tunnel-vision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on what HimBromBeere said, I have given you the delegate void.

You can pass your `Action` as a delegate in the constructor.

```
class SubButton : Button
    {
        public delegate void DoAction();
        public DoAction Action;

        public SubButton(DoAction action)
        {
            this.Action = action;
        }

        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            Action?.Invoke(); // null propogation, no need for if statements.
            base.OnClick(e);
        }
    }
```

And then using it like so:

```
var btn = new SubButton(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply pass the `Action` as delegate via constructor-injection:

```
class SubButton : Button
{
    private readonly Action action;
    public SubButton(Action action) { this.action = action; }


    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.action != null) this.action();
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

Now call it like this:

```
var btn = new SubButton(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World"));
```

Another button could do nothing:

```
var other = new SubButton(() => { });
```

This way you won´t need to create a new class for every new button, simply put the "what to do when clicking the button"-part into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First way, how do you choose your action based on EventArgs e. If e sends some value, you should create custom EventArgs class that has as a property the given value.
For example:

```
public class ActionEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ActionEventArgs(string valueName)
    {
        this.YourTypeValueName = valueName;
    }
    public YourType YourTypeValueName { get; set;}
}
```

Also, you should create CustomEventHandler like that:

```
public delegate void ActionEventHandler(object sender, ActionEventArgs args)
```

Then, you can create different methods for each action like ActionDoSth1(), ActionDoSth2, and so on.
Change your OnClick to Accept ActionEventArgs instead of EventArgs and 
then you can use switch inside OnClick, for example:

```
protected override void OnClick(ActionEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.YourTypeValueName)
    {
        case sth1:
        {
            ActionDoSth1();
        }

        break;
        case sth1:
        {
            ActionDoSth2();
        }

        break;
        ...
        ...
    }

    base.OnClick(e);
}
```

Second way is to make action virtual and for each action create child class of SubButton where you override Action as you like. 
In this case, you will have different buttons for each case and you do not need to create ActionEventArgs. Ignore this if you want all the actions in one SubButton class.